# DJango - Export Json Field in Model to CSV along with other fields

Tags: django, django-import-export

I am working on a DJango project, and in the admin I need to add an action which will export and download the contents of the model. I have successfully added the export action using import-export and it downloads the data just fine.

Currently I just subclass using

```
ImportExportActionModelAdmin
```

and it automatically shows the export option in the drop down menu.

But now the issue is, one of the fields in the model being downloaded is a JSON field and gets exported to csv as JSON itself, rightly so. I want ideas on how can i convert this JSON field into csv as well.

**Sample data that gets downloaded in the CSV:**

> {u'course_name': u'ABC', u'notes': u'Test', u'contact_mode': u'Message', u'contact_no': u'9876543210', u'stud_count': u'600', u'date': u'2018-12-19T18:30:00.000Z', u'email': u'kj@test.com', u'exp11': u'YES'}

I did some reading and seems

```
import_export.widgets.JSONWidget
```

can do the trick but am not sure how to implement this. Can some one give an example?

My Class that needs to be exported into CSV:

```
class Register(TimeStampedModel):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    details = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default={})

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.name, self.email)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using same `ImportExportActionModelAdmin` you can add function and make that field to `str`.

Comment: `JSONWidget` works only with jsonb field of postgresql. Widget for a JSON object (especially required for jsonb fields in PostgreSQL database.)

Comment: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.JSONWidget

Comment: Thanks Anup, but I already have gone through those docs, I was expecting some example snippet on how to use the JSONWidget to convert the json field along with other fields in the model like integer and string. And I am using the JSON field of postgre only, so, it must be compatible.I have edited the post to include my model.

Comment: Hi Anup, I missed you said add function and make that field to str, Can you please tell me what you mean and how to implement it. Has anyone got a solution for this problem, still trying to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, and here is how I did it for anyone who might need it.

First import the following,

```
from django.db import models
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportMixin
import json
import csv
```

Then subclass your model admin using ImportExportMixin and ModelAdmin and then add the required action as shown below.

```
class PostAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [export_json_field,]
```

Now, define the function to be called when the user selects this action on the admin page of the model

```
def export_json_field(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    '''
    Exports the JSON fields in a model to csv file
    '''        
    #Create the httpResponse object with correct csv header
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Json2Csv.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)    
    count = 0
    # print(json.dumps(queryset[0].details))    
    for obj in queryset:                   
        #loop through all the fields in the current post object
        for field in obj._meta.fields:
            #find the fields with JSONField type
            if obj._meta.get_field(field.name).get_internal_type() == 'JSONField':
                #get the contents of the json field and convert it into json format
                detail = json.dumps(getattr(obj,field.name))
                #detail = "'" + detail + "'"
                detail_parsed = json.loads(str(detail))               
                #lists to store the keys and values from the json
                keys = []
                values = []
                #loop through each json row and make a list of the keys and values
                for key, value in detail_parsed.items():
                    keys.append(key)
                    values.append(value)    
                # write the values into csv file 
                # keys form the column headers so write them only once
                if count == 0:
                    writer.writerow(keys)
                    count += 1                
                # write the values in each row
                writer.writerow(values)                
    return response

export_json_field.short_description = 'Export Json TO Csv'
```

The last line gives a name to this action that is displayed in the dropdown box in the admin page (Export Json TO Csv)

Finally, register the model admin

```
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

This will let you use the importexport functionality of the django-import-export library as well as define your own action within the same admin page.

Hope it helps.